# Cloudfront dist on top level domain

Tags: amazon-s3, dns

Is it possible to point a top level domain like http://example.com to a amazon cloudfront distribution?

I know it's possible with CNAMEs, but as far as I know, I need to set an A-name record for the top level domain in the DNS settings.

Answer (score 4):

As explained by @dgeske, this can be done.
In my case, I had not purchased the domain from `Route 53`, and hence had to do extra configuration.

**Scenario**: You have the following

1. Cloud front distribution
2. A second-level domain (example.com) **not** purchased from Amazon Route 53. It was Google domains in my case, but the idea will work for other providers also.
3. You want to point the second-level domain (example.com) to the cloud front distribution (as opposed to a subdomain like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com))

Your nomenclature is slightly inaccurate. example.com is not a TLD (top-level domain), it is what is called a second-level domain. See the following image.
[image: Parts of a URL]

**Steps to do this.**

1. Create a hosted zone in Route 53.[image: Create a hosted zone in route 53]
2. Route 53 will now give you a list of name servers that you have to set in the domain settings panel of the provider from which you purchased the domain (Google domains in my case).[image: Chaning name servers from google domains dashboard]
3. Go back to Route 53 dashboard, and create an A - Alias record for this hosted zone (use create record set option). Remember to select 'Yes' radio button.[image: A-Alias record set] Make sure you leave the subdomain part empty (since we are only interested in creating record for second-level domain).[image: leave sub-domain part empty]

Now you should be able to access your cloudfront distribution at `http://example.com`.
Depending on your DNS server, it may take a while to get records updated. 
You may configure your system to use a public DNS server such as `8.8.8.8` to verify if you are able to access the cloudfront distribution using the URL. I used firefox's `DNS over https` feature for this. This makes firefox use cloudflare's (**not** cloudfront) DNS servers. You can also use dig command line utility `dig @8.8.8.8 example.com` (My domain was fightcoronapune.com, hence, `dig @8.8.8.8 fightcoronapune.com`) (telling dig to use 8.8.8.8 DNS server to resolve names)
[image: firefox DNS over https]

You may additionally get `Access Denied` error, in which case you will have to configure the default root object for your cloudfront distribution. So that when you visit `http://example.com` the file `http://example.com/index.html` is served to you (assuming you specified index.html as default root object). ***This error has nothing to do with the steps we did above***, and you will still get this error even if you directly use your cloudfront distribution's URL given by Amazon (eg. when you go to `http://abcd.cloudfront.net directly`, instead of going to `http://example.com`).

Answer (score 3):

**Q. Can I point my zone apex (example.com versus www.example.com) at my Amazon CloudFront distribution?**

Yes. Amazon Route 53 offers a special type of record called an ‘Alias’ record that lets you map your zone apex (example.com) DNS name to your Amazon CloudFront distribution (for example, d123.cloudfront.net). IP addresses associated with Amazon CloudFront endpoints vary based on your end user’s location (in order to direct the end user to the nearest CloudFront edge location) and can change at any time due to scaling up, scaling down, or software updates. Route 53 responds to each request for an Alias record with the IP address(es) for the distribution. Route 53 doesn't charge for queries to Alias records that are mapped to a CloudFront distribution. These queries are listed as “Intra-AWS-DNS-Queries” on the Amazon Route 53 usage report.

Source: [Amazon Route 53 FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/)

Comment: This method will work if you have not purchased the domain from `Route 53`, but from somewhere else. In my case, I had purchased the domain from google domains. Just add Route 53's name servers as name servers in your domain settings. Then create an ALIAS record as mentioned in this answer from route 53 database.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you cannot create an A record for Cloudfront.

Amazon provides you with a domain name like YourName.cloudfront.net.  They need to manage the DNS resolution for that domain name behind the scenes in order to route each request to the nearest edge server.

Answer (score -1):

you can if you add alias in cloudfront
then select A or AAAA(ipv6 if enabled on cloudfront)